# Can't determine direction of $\vec{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vectors

Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ be two unit vectors such that the angle between them equals $\frac{\pi}{3}$.
Determine $\vec{x}$, knowing that:
$\vec{x}\cdot\vec{u}=-1$
$\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})=0$
$\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{v}-\vec{u})=1$
Using the last two equations I came up with something like this:[image: graph]
I can't seem to get any information out of the first equation however, so I don't know whether $\vec{x}$ is $\vec{x}_1$ or $\vec{x}_2$.
I didn't want to clutter the question with my calculations, so I didn't add them. I think the image reflects what I found well enough. I'm new to vector equations, so it is possible I overlooked something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first equation implies $\vec x_u=-\vec u,$ so that's OK. I don't think an answer with specific coordinates can be correct since we are not given the coordinates of $\vec u$ or $\vec v.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation tells us that $\vec{x}$ is in the same plane as  $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

The third equation tells us that $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{v}$ (expanding the dot product and using $\vec{x}.\vec{u}=-1$).

The first equation tells us that $|x||u| \cos \theta = -1$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{u}$, so $\cos \theta$ must be negative, and is infact equal to $5 \pi / 6$ (since the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $\pi/3$).

So $\vec{x}$ is $\vec{x}_2$ in your diagram, and its length is $2/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @DavidK thanks, fixed (I think!)

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: Yeah, should have guessed from the sign since norms are positive. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are linearly independent. It follows that $\vec u\times\vec v$ is a nonzero vector orthogonal to the plane spanned by $\vec u$ and $\vec v$. Your second equation then says that $\vec x$ is a vector in this plane. This means that
$$\vec x=\lambda\vec u+\mu \vec v\tag{1}$$
for certain real constants $\lambda$, $\mu$. The other two equations then say that
$$-1=\vec x\cdot\vec u=\lambda +\mu(\vec v\cdot\vec u)=\lambda+{1\over2}\mu\tag{2}$$
and
$$0=\vec x\cdot \vec v=\lambda(\vec u\cdot\vec v)+\mu={1\over2}\lambda +\mu\ .\tag{3}$$
The equations $(2)\wedge(3)$ determine $\lambda$ and $\mu$, so that the $\vec x$ in $(1)$ is uniquely determined by $\vec u$ and $\vec v$.

Comment: I came up with something similar, though not quite like this. Thanks Christian.